# Can Silhouette score compare algorithms based on different metrics?

Tags: clustering, k-means

If I intend to compare the clustering performance between K-Means and K-Modes clustering using this measure. How do I do so? y data set is binary in nature and I want to see if K-Modes using Manhattan distance does better than the K-Means that uses Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you should use the same metric if you want a fair comparison. And then you'll likely have that method win, which optimizes the same metric that you evaluate with. I'd definitely recommend to look at both results!

Note that k-means does *not* optimize Euclidean distances, but only squared Euclidean (c.f. Weber-Fermat problem)...

So you probably should include:

- k-means (squared Euclidean)
- k-modes (Hamming distance)
- k-medians (Manhattan distance)
- PAM k-medoids with Euclidean distance
- PAM k-medoids with squared Euclidean distance
- PAM k-medoids with Manhattan distance